# Querying a Eloquent relationship with nested table values

Tags: eloquent

I have an eloquent relationship for an object but I don't have an idea to filter the inner objects of the main object passing parameters.

There is an object called **Venue** in our project. It has many **Classes** objects. The class object belongs to many **categories** and has one **Instructor** object. We have the **Categories** table too. What I am trying to do is filter the **class objects** of the **venue** object using  category_id in Category table and instructor_id in Instructor table.

```
    $Venue = Venue::with('categories')
                    ->with('classes.schedules')
                    ->with('classes.categories')
                    ->with('classes.instructor')
                    ->rentable()
                    ->findOrFail($venue_id);
```

I expect to pass the class_category_id and instructor_id to **'classes.categories'** and **'classes.instructor'** to filter classes of the single venue.

Comment: Please add the migrations of all the tables involved.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I could resolve the issue by fetching and querying class separately without fetching venue.